# Polar renal scarring in pyelonephritis?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, human-anatomy, pathology, kidney

Why does infection and scarring occurs at poles in Vesicoureteric reflux but not in Obstructive pyelonephritis?

[image: Harsh Mohan textbook of pathology 7e, pgno:670]

It is said in Robbins that, it is due to polar papillae being flattened or concave unlike convex lateral papillae, but why is it not the case in obstructive pyelonephritis?

Also why polar papillae are not convex?

Answer (score 1):

It's more an issue of the extent of reflux than anything else. If you look at [the data](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.3109/02841858709177378) on scarring, you'll see that grade III and IV VUR present with lateral scarring as well. So, any pyelonephritis that is associated with gross dilation of the ureter and collecting system will give diffuse scarring. Mild dilation, you'll get scarring where the reverse flow goes first. I can't answer the question about *why* the reverse flow goes to the poles first. The authors of the paper I linked have their own speculation. Robbins has another. Neither have evidence on the mechanism.